# How to install ANTLWorks 2.1?

Tags: software-installation

I want to install ANTLWorks 2.1 on an Ubuntu machine, does not matter as a standalone app or as a NetBeans 7.3 plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Just [download the zipped binaries](http://tunnelvisionlabs.com/downloads/antlr/2013-07-21-antlrworks-2.1.zip), unzip it and run the `bin/antlrworks2` shell script.

Comment: I have followed your steps, antlrworks was complaining about the java version, so I have upgraded it to OpenJDK 1.7.0_25. Now when I am running it from a terminal or by double clicking on it, nothing happens. No message, no UI, no response!

Comment: Don't double click it. Open a console and execute the shell script from there. Most likely you will see an error on the console indicating why things are not working.